# array printing out twice after sorting

Tags: java

I am trying to sort my array, but for some reason it prints out a second time - before the sorted results?

```
            int []arrayLoterry= new int[50];
            String output="";

            for(int i=0;i<arrayLoterry.length;i++){
                arrayLoterry[i]=(int) Math.floor(Math.random()*49)+i;
                output+=arrayLoterry[i]+" ";

                if(i%10==9){
                    output+="\n";
                }
            }
            System.out.println(output);

    /************WHERE IT STARTS SORTING****************************/

            int temp;
            for(int i=0;i<arrayLoterry.length;i++){
                for(int j=i+1;j<arrayLoterry.length;j++){
                    if(arrayLoterry[i]>arrayLoterry[j]){
                        temp= arrayLoterry[j];
                        arrayLoterry[j]=arrayLoterry[i];
                        arrayLoterry[i]=temp;
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
            for(int j=0;j<arrayLoterry.length;j++){
               output+=arrayLoterry[j]+" ";
               if(j%10==9){
                   output+="\n";
               }
            }

            System.out.println(output);
```

What this gives (simplified by editor):

```
5 3 2 1
7 9 4 0

5 3 2 1
7 9 4 0
0 1 2 3
4 5 7 9
```

why is it printing out again after I do the sorting?

Comment: Hint for the next time: your output is **text** as well. There is no point in creating a screenshot that shows it. Just do copy / paste using that text. I took the freedom to edit your question to show your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple:

You are not printing the array directly. You keep adding the stuff you intend to print to that string variable output to collect the rows.

And you forgot to **reset** that variable. In other words: you push data into output, print output, you **add** more lines to output; and print it again.

A better way to do what you want:

- create a **new** `StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder()` before each loop
- during the loop do `builder.append(whatever)`
- after the loop, do `System.out.println(builder.toString())`

That is more efficient regarding the concatenation of strings in this case, and it will "collect" your output *once* per loop.

Comment: Kudos for guiding than just giving away the code !!

Comment: thats riiiiggght!!! I completely forgot that the string variable wasnt gonna reset by itself after the print. thanks :)